# Get current_version in rst file of readthedocs theme

Tags: jinja2, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, read-the-docs

On a readthedocs / Sphinx project, I need to display `current_version` in rst file and to generate link with the `current_version`.

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I've seen it in templates ([versions.html](https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx_rtd_theme/blob/master/sphinx_rtd_theme/versions.html#L6)):

```
v: {{ current_version }}
```

Is it possible to access *{{ current_version }}* in rst ? I've tried

```
|current_version|
```

But the result is

```
WARNING: Undefined substitution referenced: "current_version".
```

Precisions :

it work with `|version|` which is declared in `conf.py`. but I don't know how to display `current_version`.

Edit 2 :

My point was not clear sorry. In a readthedocs project, I've got several branch of documentation. In my rst files, I need to know the branch to build special links http://xxx.xx/**branch**/ because I've to store data in another repository. In the `conf.py`, there is the version field but, I want to get the branch automatically.
And I saw that in the RTD template, in file `version.html`, there is `{{ current_version }}` which is displayed in the screenshot.

Comment: thx, it answers a part of the question : how to use a variable in rst. But it doesn't work with current_version

Comment: Do you have any reference for the `current_version` you mention? Because it's not in the Sphinx nor in the RTD documentation!

Comment: I've put a screenshot. I didn't found documenation. It's in the RTD theme in version.html.

Comment: If you can't provide a link to the source code there's no way for us to know what that `current_version` is because it's not included in any of the official documentation, please edit the question to include a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @CyrilJ good job editing the post, I'm voting to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

Read the Docs injects extra `html_context` when building (see https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/blob/725e21813313ce67ca0048d72fcfdce019ee8182/readthedocs/doc_builder/templates/doc_builder/conf.py.tmpl#L75-L125). That extra context contains the `current_version` variable you are looking for.

This context is passed to the template engine. So, from `jinja2` template engine, you could use `{{ current_version }}`.

However, take into account that this does not work locally because your local build of Sphinx won't be injecting this extra context. If you want to emulate what Read the Docs docs to test this locally, you can add the following to your `conf.py`:

```py
html_context = {
 'current_version': 'my-current-version',
}
```

and build the documentation locally to check its behavior.

Also, take a look at this FAQ entry in the Read the Docs' official documentation: https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-change-behavior-when-building-with-read-the-docs